# Conversion of sahi pro Elementstub to sahi base Elementstub

Tags: java, automation, browser-automation, sahi

I have used sahi pro automation tool. The code for setting value to a text box is done using sahi base like textbox("username").setValue("jimmy"). But on run time this piece of code gets changed into sahi pro code like _sahi._textbox("username").setvalue("klj").
Now I want to know the reason why does it happen and secondly how to convert it to sahi Base or how to tackle such a problem to run my code in Sahi Base Environment??

Comment: What do you mean by Sahi Base and Sahi Base Environment? Also, are you using the java driver of Sahi? Eventually, all the code is executed in browser in javascript. So _sahi._textbox("username") is basically javascript code.

Comment: sir  I use Java to write code and controller mode is also set to java in sahi.properties.

Comment: the issue that i am facing is on sending values using .setValue("xxx") is not working when used in any automation framework, however, using the same code independently works well..

Comment: and this is something that I get on console:---error:Playback session not started. Verify that proxy is set on the browser.------whereas proxy is properly set to 9999 in my ie browser

Comment: You have a lot of variables here. What automation framework are you using? You created one yourself? Why are you writing the code in java in the first place? If this is not a strict requirement, you can actually try the Sahi scripting language. I am not sure if they have continuous support for java driver or not. If your code works well independently, then problem is not with Sahi but your automation framework. You might want to get support from the team if you are using pro. They provide support during evaluation as well.

Comment: Sir but its not Sahi pro......and the error on console is ---error:Playback session not started. Verify that proxy is set on the browser---this is something I am unable to understand..

Comment: but its not Sahi pro -> Are you using Sahi Open source or the pro version. And it's not possible to figure out what is wrong with the information you are providing.

Comment: exactly its sahi open source.....

Comment: Please try in the Sahi forums then. You will have a better shot. I haven't worked with Sahi OS.